# Getting error in apex test class while deploying in production.?

Tags: apextestrunresult

I have a objective Area with field name (Org with master-detail relationship). For the field Org I have a filter called (Org.status equals active). Status is Org object field.

I have a test apex class

Org__c k == new Org__c();
k.Name == 'Test Org';
insert k;

While deploying in production I'm getting error like Org field Filter criteria is don't match.
How to resolve that error in apex test class.

Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create org object that satifies ur filter criteria and test the apex class

```
Org__c k == new Org__c();
k.Name == 'Test Org';
k.isActive=true
insert k;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked